# Primary key for inserting in database using linq

Tags: sql, linq, primary-key

why it is necessary to have column with **PRIMARY KEY** for **INSERT** , **DELETE** , **UPDATE** in database using **LINQ**?

Comment: Why doesn't your table have a primary key?

Comment: Linq doesn't do updates - do you mean Entity Framework?  or Linq-to-SQL?

Comment: I know a table should have a primary key but without it we still can perform operation using SQL but why we cant do it using LINQ?

Comment: Say you have a table with 3 identical rows.  How would LINQ know which one to remove?